# Uploading images to S3 Bucket using AWS Storage in react-native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I am designing a social media application using react-native and AWS Amplify tools. This is my first time using AWS Amplify so I am trying my best to understand how it all works. I am trying to implement a feature that allows users to upload a profile picture along with multiple images and have them displayed on their profile. The issue I am having right now is understanding how to connect my AWS API (GraphQL) to the AWS Storage (S3 Buckets).

A little background on my project setup first. At the moment, I have authentication working with the Amplify Auth tool and I can correctly run GraphQL mutations using the Amplify API. The issues started when I tried to use the Amplify Storage tool.

I have tried multiple approaches, one of them being including an array of S3Objects in my GraphQL schema as shown here

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  userName: String! @index(name: "byUserName", queryField: "userByUserName")
  bio: String!
  streak: Int!
  profile_pic: S3Object
  gallery: [S3Object]
}

type S3Object {
  bucket: String!
  region: String!
  key: String!
}
```

There were two issues with this approach. The first was when I ran my createUser mutation, I was required to enter in a key for the profile_pic and the gallery since they are both S3Objects. I was under the impression that profile_pic and gallery would simply be a pointer to an S3Object and an array of S3Objects respectfully. The second issue was when I tried to upload a default profile picture to my bucket and use that as the key for my profile_pic S3Object, I was told that my user was not authorized to use mutations.

To put this issue into simple terms, I am looking for a way to allow my application users to create/update, read, and delete their own photos from my S3Bucket.